# How to sum 2 pandas Series with diffent rows treating NaN as 0

Tags: pandas, series

I have 2 pandas Series, like this

```
bananas    3.0
apples     2.0
avocados   4.0
```

```
bananas     2.0
apples      5.0
pineapple   1.0
```

If I just sum them, it returns this:

```
apples      7.0
avocados    NaN
bananas     5.0
pineapple   NaN
```

but what I want is

```
apples      7.0
avocados    4.0
bananas     5.0
pineapple   1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `concat` with `groupby`:

```
pd.concat([s1,s2]).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Or `.add` with `fill_value` option:

```
s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)
```